# Angularfire: connection closed on $destroy?

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I have a question regarding firebase-connections in Angularfire and how long they remain open while navigating through an angular app. What I am trying to understand is when a scope gets destroyed ( e.g. on changing view or state ) will the remaining connection also be closed. According to firebase a connection remains open unless you specifically close it yourself ( e.g. off() ) but in angular my scope variable is destroyed.

```
$scope.myFirebaseObj = $firebaseObject(ref);
```

The reason I am asking is the concern for memory leaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection to Firebase servers will remain open from the first time a connection is made, until either the app (or the browser window/tab) is closed or until you explicitly call `goOffline()`.

I [checked the AngularFire code](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/search?q=gooffline&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93), it never calls `goOffline()`.

When you call `$destroy()` it in turn [calls `off()`](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/src/FirebaseObject.js#L410-L414). That will cancel the listen/subscription, so that you don't receive further data updated. But the connection will remain open.