# What is the difference between .valueChanges() and .get()

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am wonder what is the difference between `.valueChanges()` and `.get()`

Here is the signatures:
`valueChanges():  Observable<T[]>;`
`get(options?: firestore.GetOptions): Observable<firestore.QuerySnapshot>;`

If you take a look at this tow calls they returns the same result:

```
this.firestore.collection('version').valueChanges().subscribe(x => {
  console.log;
});

this.firestore.collection('version').get().subscribe(x => {
  console.log;
});
```

It is seems like in case of `.get()` you can play with `GetOptions:  'server' | 'cache'` is there other benefits?

In my particular use case I just want to take the data from the server and disconnect, I want to minimize the number of connections to firebase as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get()` just fetches data a single time.

`valueChanges()` allows your code to observe changes that happen to documents over time.

Choose the one that meets the needs of your app.  If you don't need to be updated with changes to documents as they happen, then don't use `valueChanges()`.

Neither of these establishes any "connections".  All Firestore operations are pipelined over a single connection maintained by the SDK.

Comment: oh i c, so by using .get()  you do not have to use `.pipe(first())` to take one and unsubscribe automatically, right?

Comment: Yes, get() only ever produces one snapshot.

Comment: Does that mean that `.get()` immediately closing the connection? If not, how would you close it?

Comment: There is only ever one connection, it's fully managed by the SDK, and stays open as long as possible.  All requests go through that one connection.

Comment: so basically `.get()` does not close the connection right?

Comment: The connection does not close due to **any** type of query. The SDK keeps it open.

Comment: just looked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35406169/angularfire-connection-closed-on-destroy is there anyway to close the connection?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it separately.  Be sure to explain the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

1. ***get()*** is a method to fetch data
2. ***valueChanges()*** is a multicasting observable that emits an event every time the value of the control changes, in the UI or programmatically

*Difference:*

get() can get data only once, whereas valueChanges() is automatically fired whenever something changes and retrieve data (observer) by subscribe()